# trying to scrape facebook posts and comments with beautifulsoap

Tags: selenium, facebook, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape posts and comments out of Facebook, I'm using Beautifulsoup.

I get the part:

```
 url = 'https://www.facebook.com/ameedcoffee'
 response=requests.get(url)
 soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text,'html.parser')
```

But then when i try to catch of any of the div tags i get len = 0 as if these div tags do not exist

```
 cards= soup.find_all('div','kvgmc6g5 cxmmr5t8 oygrvhab hcukyx3x c1et5uql ii04i59q')
 len(cards)
```

I'm not familiar with selenium and this is only my second job scraping.
can you please help me understand what I'm doing wrong? And if I'm to use selenium, how to begin the code?

Comment: _"can you please help me understand what I'm doing wrong?"_ - you are trying to scrape a website, that does absolutely not want you to do this. This is against Facebook's ToS, and they undertake technical measures against it as well (like, regularly switching out those cryptic class names for different ones.)

Answer (score 0):

Facebook uses a framework called (ReactJS) which makes dynamic class names like "xzx_sdsd-sds" and they change every time they make a new release.

Maybe if you want to scrap, you may have to crawl the Facebook HTML-only version found on cheap phones.It used to be available at https://m.facebook.com but things might  have changed

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).